# How to remove comma separator before submitting form to a server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, number-formatting

I am working on a form with user input. This is my code:

```
<form role="search" id="default-search" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" novalidate>

    <input class="number" name="price-from" placeholder="Cena od" maxlength = "11" min = "0">

</form>
```

1. First i want to automatically format user input from e.g. 10000 to 10,000 to have a clearer view on what was typed

My code for converting user input is:

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // format number
  jQuery(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
  });
});
```

And for now everything works fine.

**BUT!**

When submitting this form, server is "thinking" that 10,000 = 10, not 10000.

So, what i need to do, is to convert back 10,000 to 10000 so server is counting it properly.

I need user to see formatted version of his input (like 10,000), while server should use plain number without commas (like 10000).

Any ideas much appriciated. Thanks!

Comment: Checkout the [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) to format the number with seperators for your users. And don't mutate the original value but store it and use it in your form. Use either [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the value from string to number.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are using type cast, so getting 10 as an output instead of 10000. So, it is truncating the character from the starting index of character (i.e. comma).

You can replace the comma and get the desired output.

```
var num = "10,000";
num = num.replace(',','');
```

Then, pass it to server side.

Answer (score 0):

use this one to remove comma or all commas of your text

```
let num = "10,000"
num = num.replace(/,/g, ''),
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using the current Regex and replace approach:

You can just add a function that will use regex and the [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to remove all comma separators and then convert the input value to an integer using the [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function when you are ready to submit the form like this:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // format number
  jQuery(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
  });
});

jQuery('#btn').click(function(){
 const valueToSubmit  = parseInt(jQuery('input.number').val().replace(/,/, ""));
  alert("Submitting the value " + valueToSubmit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="search" id="default-search" action="#" novalidate>
    <input class="number" name="price-from" placeholder="Cena od" maxlength = "11" min = "0">
    <button type="button" id="btn">Submit number</button>
</form>
```

### Using the toLocaleString method:

You can just use the the [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method along with the [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to automatically add comma separators to your input value and then converting them back to their original value when you want to submit the input value to your server like this:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery('input.number').on('input', function(e) {
  e.target.value = parseInt(e.target.value.replace(/,/g, "")).toLocaleString();
});

jQuery('#btn').click(function() {
  const valueToSubmit = parseInt(jQuery('input.number').val().replace(/,/g, ""));
  alert("Submitting the value " + valueToSubmit);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="search" id="default-search" action="#" novalidate>
    <input class="number" name="price-from" placeholder="Cena od" maxlength = "11" min = "0">
    <button type="button" id="btn">Submit number</button>
</form>
```

With **pure JavaScript**, the above jQuery would look like this:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#default-search input[name="price-from"]');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  input.value = parseInt(input.value.replace(/,/g, "")).toLocaleString();
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const valueToSubmit = parseInt(input.value.replace(/,/g, ""));
  alert("Submitting the value " + valueToSubmit);
})
```

```html
<form role="search" id="default-search" action="#" novalidate>
    <input class="number" name="price-from" placeholder="Cena od" maxlength = "11" min = "0">
    <button type="button" id="btn">Submit number</button>
</form>
```

---

### Using the Intl.NumberFormat object:

Another similar approach to do this would be to use the [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) object along with the [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to automatically add comma separators to your input value and then converting them back to their original value when you want to submit the input value to your server like this:

```js
$('input[name="price-from"]').on('input', function(e) {
  e.target.value = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(parseInt(e.target.value.replace(/,/g, "")))
});

$('#btn').click(function() {
  const valueToSubmit = parseInt($('input[name="price-from"]').val().replace(/,/g, ""));
  alert("Submitting the value " + valueToSubmit);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="search" id="default-search" action="#" novalidate>
  <input class="number" name="price-from" placeholder="Cena od" maxlength = "11" min = "0">
  <button type="button" id="btn">Submit number</button>
</form>
```

With **pure JavaScript**, the above jQuery would look like this:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#default-search input[name="price-from"]');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  input.value = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(parseInt(input.value.replace(/,/g, "")))
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const valueToSubmit = parseInt(input.value.replace(/,/g, ""));
  alert("Submitting the value " + valueToSubmit);
})
```

```html
<form role="search" id="default-search" action="#" novalidate>
  <input class="number" name="price-from" placeholder="Cena od" maxlength = "11" min = "0">
  <button type="button" id="btn">Submit number</button>
</form>
```